# Non-zero prime ideal of ring of integers is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

I am looking at a lemma in my class note under "*The Field of Fractions of Dedekind Domain*" as follow:

> LEMMA: Assume that $R$ is an integrally closed noetherian domain of Krull dimension 1. Then each non-zero prime ideal of $R$ is invertible.

I would like to better appreciate this lemma by doing it the dumb way: Giving myself with an example, and looks like $\mathbb Z$ is the simplest example:

(a) I read somewhere that $\mathbb Z$ is notherian domain of dimension 1. 
(b) $\mathbb Z$ is integrally closed in $\mathbb Q$, because $\mathbb Q$ is integral closure of $\mathbb Z$. (I am not sure if I saying it correctly here.). 
(c) The simplest non-zero prime ideal of $\mathbb Z$ is $(2) = 2 \mathbb Z$. 
(d) Having said all the above, how should I express mathematicaly that the prime ideal $2\mathbb Z$ is invertible?

Thank you all very much for your time and effort.

Comment: *(I am not sure if I saying it correctly here.)* The integral closure of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Z$, not $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: *The simplest non-zero prime ideal of $\mathbb Z$ is $(2) = 2 \mathbb Z$* Er, I'm not really sure what your criterion for "simple" is here. The prime ideals $(p)$ for $p$ prime all look pretty much the same to me.

Comment: Maybe I should say "the most immediate" rather than "the simplest" example. Sorry, dump phrases! But thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Having said all the above, how should I express mathematicaly that the prime ideal $2ℤ$ is invertible?

As [the wiki page mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal#Definition_and_basic_results) you could just compute $(\Bbb Z:(2))=\{x\in \Bbb Q\mid (2)x\subseteq \Bbb Z\}=\frac12\Bbb Z\subseteq \Bbb Q$, and see that $(2)(\Bbb Z:(2))=\Bbb Z$.